# Elasticsearch river plugin for Neo4j: NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class with value [neo4j]]

Tags: neo4j, elasticsearch

I am trying to make ES work with Neo4j and I followed the steps you said on the documentation. The thing is that I am having difficulties getting the connection done. ES doesn't has the values of NEo4j.

When I check for indexes on the ES the "_river" index is well created but some errors appear when i do:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_river/_search?pretty=true&q=:
```

Here is the error:

> {"error":"NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class with value
>   [neo4j]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[neo4j];
>   ","node":{"id":"2rDeNA46SJ63jYFlpoGfKQ","name":"Zip-Zap","transport_address":"inet[/10.140.28.166:9300]"}}

When i get all the indexes from ES

```
(curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=1)
```

I get:

```
{
  "_river" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  }
```

Do you have an idea about what is the problem?

PS: the version used was the 1.1.1

The error is:

> NoClassSettingsException Failed to load class with value neo4j nested:
>   ClassNotFoundException neo4j

Complete response:
http://p.shrib.com/lsfnzF3H?v=nc&s=m

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and I think the [installation instructions](https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-neo4j) are **missing one step**:

> Download "elasticsearch-river-neo4j-1.2.1.1.jar" from [Click here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sksamuel/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-neo4j/1.2.1.1/elasticsearch-river-neo4j-1.2.1.1.jar) and copy it to "HOME_DIRECTORY_OF_ES/lib" folder.

Doing this and an elasticsearch restart solved it for me.

Found at: [Examples about Integration of Elasticsearch with neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323323/examples-about-integration-of-elasticsearch-with-neo4j)