# Examples about Integration of Elasticsearch with neo4j

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j

I have installed Elasticsearch as well as Neo4j. I want to integrate Elasticsearch with Neo4j using "Neo4j River Plugin for ElasticSearch" plugIn. Can anybody tell me how to integrate these two.
I am also looking for some use case example where i will have clear understanding of how noe4j works with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should have Elasticsearch & Neo4j has to be installed. To integrate with Neo4j River Plugin, we need to install the plugIn using the following command from the home directory of Elasticsearch (Both Elasticsearch & Neo4j has to run ) : 
`bin/plugin -install com.sksamuel.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-neo4j/1.2.1.1`

Then download "elasticsearch-river-neo4j-1.2.1.1.jar" from [Click here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sksamuel/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-neo4j/1.2.1.1/elasticsearch-river-neo4j-1.2.1.1.jar) and copy it to "HOME_DIRECTORY_OF_ES/lib" folder.

Then start the Neo4J River server by curling command :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/my_neo_river/_meta' -d '{
"type": "neo4j",
"neo4j": {
    "uri": "<NEO4J_URI>",
    "interval": <some interval in ms (only the number)>
},

"index": {
    "name": "<INDEX_NAME>",
    "type": "<TYPE>"
}
```

}'

**Note :**

**uri**      :   The full URI to the neo4j server, eg http://localhost:7474/db/data

**interval** : The time (in ms) between polling the neo4j instance. The greater this   value, the lower the load on the server but the longer between updates in neo4j being reflected inside elastic.

**index.name** :    The name of the index to index nodes into. It should be in small letter.

**index.type** :    The type to use for indexing.

Use RestClient (e.g : Postman) to query for data in elasticsearch to verify the integration. The url for query has to look like `http://localhost:9200/<index_name>/_search?q=<search_property>:<search_value>`

Comment: Is this solution still vaild ?

Comment: There are several way of integrating Neo4j with ElasticSearch. In the past the easiest were River plugins which have been discontinued. You can integrate with Neo4j’s TransactionEventHandler to push graph changes directly to ElasticSearch. Another option is to supply sources and sinks for LogStash and another is to implement a full index-provider that uses ES as storage. This is a tight integration which might suffer from the roundtrip latencies to ElasticSearch’s REST API.

Comment: @shaw.ram any working examples of neo-es integration using transactionEventhandler or anything else using python?

Comment: @Ajay Singh Though i have not tried it personally but i googled about it and found a git project - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch.

Comment: @RCS I'm using this only. Customising this library to set "required=false" and few minor customizations. let me know if you have any leads