# Elasticsearch Store 'searchable' list

Tags: elasticsearch

I have access to a Neo4J Graph Database that stores a list of people and the relationships between them (friend). I am looking to implement a "search friends list" function that performs a search within a given users friends list. I am concerned about performance so I am looking to implement this search using Elasticsearch; however i am not sure how to index the user data from Neo4j in Elasticsearch to facilitate the above-mentioned query. A typical use-case is "for user x find his friends whose name starts with "Mik". The SearchAPI is build on SpringWeb using Elasticsearch JavaAPI.

**EDIT 1:**

What I am asking is different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323323/examples-about-integration-of-elasticsearch-with-neo4j) in that I know how to use Elasticsearch rivers and other tools to index data. My question seeks to establish the best approach to implement functionality such as "search_friends_list". For example, do I use the unique user identifier of each user as a type (something like `..:9200/users/[username]`) and index each one of a given users friends to that index and type? This way if I want to search through a list of user JackSparrow's friends I'd perform something akin to `..:9200/users/JackSparrow/_search?q=search_term`. This example smells though and would probably lead to serious performance degradation when the number of user's in my system grows. Thats where I need assistance and advice. What approaches exist to implement a solution for such?

**EDIT 2: removed Neo4J tags, provided more info**

**Mapping**

```
{
    "people": {
        "mappings": {
            "friends": {
                "properties": {
                    "firstname": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "friends": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "fullname": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "lastname": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "username": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "userid": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
{
    "_index": "people",
    "_type": "friends",
    "_id": "24482ba5-06fa-2f58-2560-4b8fa5e3d1a7",
    "_score": 11.5473,
    "_source": {
        "firstname": "Carl",
        "id": 4735,
        "fullname": "Carl Platt",
        "userid": "24482ba5-06fa-2f58-2560-4b8fa5e3d1a7",
        "friends": [
            "8248f90b-3c30-b60a-d64f-ced55304fcb0",
            "8b4a0960-f792-87d5-be4d-17a53963c29e",
            "904a4d6f-c7ce-8ae3-edf2-e0ac6bc69885",
            "934e0e4b-2b20-b7b1-c092-1eb22e3e92bd",
            "954e1500-7f74-468e-b611-cd35382d9aa6",
            "994cacfc-3a76-c77a-adec-b50804933490",
            "a942b4b7-cdcc-8653-ef73-a6000dbd418c",
            ...
```

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "firstname",
          "query": "Amu*"          
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "friends": {
            "index": "people",
            "type": "friends",
            "id": "24482ba5-06fa-2f58-2560-4b8fa5e3d1a7",            
            "path": "userid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is different. I only mentioned Neo4J so that no one would say "use neo4j"

Answer (score 2):

In the official documentation, there's a similar example around Twitter users and their tweets in order to illustrate the [`terms` lookup mechanism](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_terms_lookup_twitter_example), which could well do what you're looking for.

The idea would be to have one `users` index containing `user` documents. Each document representing a user would have an array property containing the ids of his friends. Let's create a simple version of the `users` index:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/users -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "friends": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Now let's index some sample data, where user 1 is friend with all other users but 4 (Mike):

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/users/user/_bulk -d '
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"id": 1, "name": "John", "friends": [2,3,5]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"id": 2, "name": "Mikil", "friends": [1,3]}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"id": 3, "name": "Maxim", "friends": [1,2]}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"id": 4, "name": "Mike", "friends": [5]}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"id": 5, "name": "Philip", "friends": [1,4]}
'
```

So I'm restating one of your typical use-cases, i.e. **"for user x find his friends whose name starts with "Mik"**. With such a set-up this can be accomplished with the following query:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/users/user/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "name",
          "query": "mik*"         <--- only friends whose name starts with "mik" 
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "friends": {
            "index": "users",
            "type": "user",
            "id": "1",            <--- only friends of user 1
            "path": "id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The results will only contain user 2 (Mikil) and not 4 (Mike). QED.

Comment: With the added value that the filter (above) which restricts the search to "only friends of user 1", is then cached so as to speed up subsequent completion requests for user 1's friends.

Comment: @Val this works brilliantly when the userID is an integer, however, when I used UUIDs (as is a requirement on my current system) it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference. Can you share some sample documents and why you think it's not working with string ids?

Comment: @Val - I added non_analyzed to the fields in question, and works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get back to you in time, but that was going to be my suggestion as well. Glad you figured it out.